# How to convert column to datetime ignoring obscure string values

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert several columns to datetime, most of which have worked, although one or two contain several unique string values that will not convert. The code I used is:

```
energy['EFD'] =  pd.to_datetime(energy['EFD'])
```

Most values for `'EFD'` are in the format `2011-05-31 00:00:00` however unlike my other columns it contains string values such as `'15 Months'`, `'36 months from start'` which messes up `.to_datetime`.

Is there a way to ignore these and change the rest to datetime?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `errors='ignore'` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). From the documentation, by using this flag:

> If a date does not meet the timestamp limitations, passing
>   errors=’ignore’ will return the original input instead of raising any
>   exception.

So you just need to apply it as

```
energy['EFD'] =  pd.to_datetime(energy['EFD'], errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I take it that these string values will be a problem when trying to use this datetime column in a Time Series later on?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Bear that in mind when using them later on.